# A generic procedure that can execute any procedure/function

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

**input**
Package name (IN)
procedure name (or function name) (IN) 
A table indexed by integer, it will contain values that will be used to execute the procedure (IN/OUT).

**E.g**
let's assume that we want to execute the procedure below

```
utils.get_emp_num(emp_name IN VARCHAR
                  emp_last_name IN VARCHAR
                  emp_num OUT NUMBER
                  result  OUT VARCHAR);
```

The procedure that we will create will have as inputs:

```
package_name = utils
procedure_name = get_emp_num
table = T[1] -> name
        T[2] -> lastname
        T[3] -> 0   (any value) 
        T[4] -> N   (any value)

run_procedure(package_name,
              procedure_name,
              table)
```

The main procedure should return the same table that has been set in the input, but with           the execution result of the procedure

```
table =  T[1] -> name
         T[2] -> lastname
         T[3] -> 78734 (new value)
         T[4] -> F     (new value)
```

any thought ?

Comment: It sounds like you've jumped to a solution when you should be describing your problem. I can't imagine this is a good way to do execute anything... so, what is your problem?

Comment: A Lua script will call a Pro*c function that will execute the procedure and return a table of data (the result) to a Lua function for further use. I didn't find a better way to get procedure result from a Lua script.

Comment: Yes, but do you need to call _every_ procedure using exactly the same call. It might be more normal to change your Pro*C call depending on the procedure you need to call rather than changing the database to call everything identically.

Comment: Pro*c is a compiled language, the Pro*c will contain the main processing for all users (the same), while the Lua script will be used as a plugin (it depends of the user, it will vary), the script will be a simple .Lua file (not binary) and will be called by simply providing the PATH to the Pro*c program. This is to avoid to supply every user with a specific version of the Pro*c code, and allow the Lua script to execute any procedure/function without amending the Pro*C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get from the all_arguments table the argument_name, data_type, in_out, and the position

Build the PLSQL block

```
DECLARE
    loop over argument_name and create the declare section
    argument_name data_type if in_out <> OUT then := VALUE OF THE INPUT otherwise NULL
BEGIN

--In the case of function create an additional argument 
function_var:= package_name.procedure_name( loop over argument_name);

--use a table of any_data, declare it as global in the package

if function then
    package_name.ad_table.EXTEND;
    package_name.ad_table(package_name.ad_table.LAST):= function_var;
end if

--loop over argument_name IF IN_OUT <> IN
package_name.ad_table.EXTEND;
package_name.ad_table(package_name.ad_table.LAST):= 

if data_type = VARCHAR2 then := ConvertVarchar2(argument_name)
else if NUMBER then ConvertNumber 
else if DATE then ConvertDate
...

END;
```

The result is stored in the table.
To get value use Access* functions

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Basically, you build a SQL statement of the following form:

```
sql := 'BEGIN utils.get_emp_num(:1, :2, :3, :4); END;';
```

Then you execute it:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql USING t(1), t(2), OUT t(3), OUT t(4);
```

Now here comes the tricky part: For each number of parameters and IN/OUT combinations you need a separate EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement. And to figure out the number of parameters and their direction, you need to query the ALL_ARGUMENTS table first.

You might be able to simplify it by passing the whole table as a bind argument instead of a separate bind argument for each table element. But I haven't quite figured out how you would do that.

And the next thing you should consider: the elements of the table T your using will have a type: VARCHAR, NUMBER etc. So the current mixture where you have both numbers and strings won't work.

BTW: Why do you want such a dynamic call mechanism anyway?

Comment: User can write his own Lua script, and request data from the DB, Lua will call a PRO*C function that will execute the procedure and return the result (the table) to the Lua script.
I've been asked to do the same think, creating a procedure that allow the execution of any query, it was easy by using DBMS_SQL package, but with procedure/function i found it to be more tricky.